# how to get newly created word document details in react js word addin

Tags: reactjs, word-addins

I have a Word Addin in react js. I am trying to get word document details.

Open word --> open addin. when i click button i need to get this newly created word document details. i can get file path. i want get document byteArray. this is my code.

```
    export const DocumentDetails = (callback) => {
  if (Office.context.document.url) {
    const DocURL = Office.context.document.url;
    const fileNameWithExtension = DocURL.split("/").pop();
    const encodedDocName = fileNameWithExtension.split(".").slice(0, -1).join(".");
    const docTitle = decodeURIComponent(encodedDocName);

    Office.context.document.getFileAsync(
      Office.FileType.Compressed,
      { sliceSize: 65536 }, // You can adjust the sliceSize as per your needs
      function (result) {
        if (result.status === Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
          const file = result.value;
          const reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onloadend = function (event) {
            if (event.target.readyState === FileReader.DONE) {
              const byteArray = new Uint8Array(event.target.result);
              callback(byteArray);
            }
          };
          reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file.slice());
        } else { 
           console.error("Error getting the document file: " + result.error.message);
        }
      }
    );
  }
};
```

Is this possible. this file is auto save into the temp file.